# Act As Votable Ajax Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to ruby and I just played around with a demo app. I've included the gem acts_as_votable, and it works quite well except for one fact that I thing its missing... ajax.
Refreshing all the time the page its a bit tedious so I've "tryed" to implement ajax, but no luck :(. After maybe two hours of resource I think I can't do nothing more. I need help on implementing ajax on down and up votes. Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

entries_controller.rb

```
  def upvote
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user.voted_for? @entry
      @entry.vote_total = @entry.vote_total + 1
      @entry.save
      @entry.upvote_by current_user
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Sorry!! You had allready voted this entry!'
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user.voted_for? @entry
      @entry.vote_total = @entry.vote_total + 1
      @entry.save
      @entry.downvote_by current_user
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Sorry!! You had allready voted this entry!'
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

_entry.html.erb (in entries folder)

```
<aside class="vote-count bind-<%= entry.id %>">
  <%= link_to like_entry_path(entry), :remote => true, method: :put, class: 'vpos' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    <%= entry.get_upvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to dislike_entry_path(entry), :remote => true, method: :put, class: 'npos' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
  <%= entry.get_downvotes.size %>
  <% end %>
</aside>
```

upvote.js.erb (in entries folder)

```
$(".bind-<%=entry.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript entry.get_upvotes.size %>');
```

routes.rb

```
resources :entries,  only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy] do
  member do
    put 'like', to: 'entries#upvote'
    put 'dislike', to: 'entries#downvote'
  end
end
```

I'm a bit new to rails so anykind of help. would be much appreciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finnaly I've managed to make it working (acts as votable gem, the votes are now ajax). I'm going to share it incase someone has the same issue as me.

routes.rb :

```
put 'like', to: 'entries#upvote'
put 'dislike', to: 'entries#downvote'
```

entries_controller.rb (in my case):

```
def upvote
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
  unless current_user.voted_for? @entry
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { render :layout => false }
    @entry.vote_total = @entry.vote_total + 1
    @entry.save
    @entry.upvote_by current_user
  else
    flash[:danger] = 'You allready voted this entry'
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js
  end
 end
end

def downvote
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
  unless current_user.voted_for? @entry
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { render :layout => false }
    @entry.vote_total = @entry.vote_total + 1
    @entry.save
    @entry.downvote_by current_user
  else
    flash[:danger] = 'You allready voted this entry'
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js
  end
 end
end
```

_entry.html.erb (partial):

```
<aside class="vote-count bind-<%= entry.id %>">
 <%= link_to like_entry_path(entry), :remote => true, method: :put, class: 'vpos' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
  <span class="vcount-<%= entry.id %>"><%= entry.get_upvotes.size %></span>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to dislike_entry_path(entry), :remote => true, method: :put, class: 'npos' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
  <span class="ncount-<%= entry.id %>"><%= entry.get_downvotes.size %></span>
 <% end %>
</aside>
```

upvote.js.erb:

```
$('.vpos').bind('ajax:success', function() {
 $('.vcount-<%= @entry.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @entry.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');
});
```

downvote.js.erb:

```
$('.npos').bind('ajax:success', function() {
 $('.ncount-<%= @entry.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @entry.get_downvotes.size.to_s %>');
});
```

That's all. Hope that I can help someone that needs a hand with this. 
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this! Super-helpful. I have a question about your js.erb files -- what is the function of these, and where are you putting them? Doesn't Rails' :remote => true handle the AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. 
The project : The user can create a post (debat) and the other users can upvote and downvote with buttons.

What is different:

The ajax refresh the downvoteS count and the upvotes count at the same time when a user clicks. 
I used .text in place of .html in my javascript files. 
I didn't use a partial, I placed all my code in the debat.html.erb. 
I created specific class for each button with a span and a variable id, because all the buttons changed at the same time

My routes.rb is the same:

```
resources :debats do
 member do
  put "like", to:    "debats#upvote"
  put "dislike", to: "debats#downvote"
 end
end
```

dabats_controller.rb :

```
def upvote
  @debat = Debat.find(params[:id])
  @debat.upvote_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @debat.liked_count } }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
end

def downvote
  @debat = Debat.find(params[:id])
  @debat.downvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html {redirect_to :back }
   format.json { render json: { count: @debat.disliked_count } }
   format.js   { render :layout => false }
 end
end
```

debat.html.erb (only the part with the 2 buttons)

```
 <div class="large-1 columns count">
    <span class= "like-<%= debat.id %>">
      <%= link_to like_debat_path(debat), method: :put, remote: true, class: 'like' do %>
        <div class="upcount"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></div>
        <div class="ouicount up-<%= debat.id %>"><%= debat.get_upvotes.size %></div>
        <div class="oui">Oui</div>
      <%end%>
    </span>

    <span class= "dislike-<%= debat.id %>"> 
      <%= link_to dislike_debat_path(debat), method: :put, remote: true, class: 'dislike' do %>
        <div class="non">Non</div>
        <div class="noncount down-<%= debat.id%>"> <%= debat.get_downvotes.size %></div>
        <div class="downcount"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
      <% end %>
    </span>
  </div>
```

upvote.js.erb

```
$('.like').bind('ajax:success', function() {

   $('.up-<%= @debat.id %>').text(<%= @debat.get_upvotes.size%>);
   $('.down-<%= @debat.id %>').text(<%= @debat.get_downvotes.size%>);

});
```

downvote.js.erb

```
$('.dislike').bind('ajax:success', function() {

 $('.up-<%= @debat.id %>').text(<%= @debat.get_upvotes.size%>);
 $('.down-<%= @debat.id %>').text(<%= @debat.get_downvotes.size%>);

});
```

Hope it helps !